# Java Mail API - Send Partial Mail

Tags: jakarta-mail

I want to send the mail partially,that is,in-case one of the specified email addresses do no exist,the mail be sent to the remaining ones.This can be done by setting the following property "mail.smtp.sendpartial" to get the Session Instance.However,I am still unable to send it partially (i.e. only to valid email Addresses).

Any other possible issues?

Answer (score 0):

So this is not a programmatic error. Your code works just as fine.

The problem is that the remote mail server thinks that your mail is

potentially harmful and thus rejects such messages. try to send mail

to some mail server installed in your local machine and see if it runs as you wanted.

For this install some mail server like Mercury Mail Server or Oxygen Mail Server etc.

Happy New Year :)               .

Answer (score 0):

Turn on Session debugging.  What's the protocol trace show?